# Targeting title with Bootstrap hidden command

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which creates a previous and next link for my Wordpress post. I want to hide the link's title and replace the link title with the text 'back' and 'next'

Current code hides the icon placed beside the title (indicating Bootstrap is working ) but doesn't hide the title

```
    <nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $nav_id ); ?>" class="<?php echo $nav_class; ?>">

<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

    <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="hidden-xs fa fa-chevron-up icn-L"></span>'. _x( get_previous_post()->post_title, '<span class="hidden-xs">Next post link</span>', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
    <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',  _x( get_next_post()->post_title, 'Previous post link', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="hidden-xs fa fa-chevron-up icn-R"></span>' ); ?>

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited answer

```
<?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="hidden-xs fa fa-chevron-up icn-L">%title</span><span class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm ">Back</span>' ); ?>

<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',  '<span class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm ">Next</span><span class="hidden-xs fa fa-chevron-up icn-R">%title</span>' ); ?>
```

Comment: That works for turning into back/next on mobile, but removes the title on lagre screens (which I want to keep)

Comment: awesome! sorry forgot to mention how can the next post be written to act the same?

Comment: Please explain your question.

Comment: my apologies I didn't see the code changes. Alls good, thank you very much for your help